# Can I connect one PCIE_CLKREQ# pin from SoC to two different devices?

Tags: pcb-design, usb, pcie, usb-host

In my design, I'm using [VL805](https://www.via-labs.com/product_show.php?id=48) USB 3.0 Host Controller which takes 1 lane of PCIe and outputs 4 ports of USB3.2 Gen 1.

The platform which I'm building is based on AMD V3000 CPU.

My question is,  if want to use two chips of VL805, so I can get 8 USB 3.0 ports, can I connect one PCIE_CLKREQ# pin to two devices?

looks like I'm running out of CLK REQUEST signals form the SoC, and since all USB 3.0 functionality on the platform should be the same, I thought about using the same PCIE_CLKREQ# (lets say it's PCIE_CLKREQ#4 for example).